# Should pagination cursor contain encoded query parameters?

Tags: pagination, cursor

Recently I am drowning in two school of thought about cursor designation for paging:

1. Cursor contains only its position (like last item id, last created at ...).

   So server can serve any combination of cursor and query parameter.

   For example:

   - First query: `?queryParam=X&cursor=`, server responds with `cursor=C1`
   - Second query: `?queryParam=Y&cursor=C1`, server still able to handle this query with new query parameter (even though `cursor=C1` is associated with query parameter X)
2. Cursor contains original query parameters. When specify cursor, other query parameters are disregarded.

   That is if query with incompatible query params <-> cursor pair, the server may ignore query params or even responds with error

   - First query: `?queryParam=X&cursor=`, server responds with `cursor=C1` which encodes `queryParam=X`
   - Second query: `?queryParam=Y&cursor=C1`, server extract `queryParam=X` from `cursor=C1` and ignore `queryParam=Y` from request.

So what is a prefer approach to design a cursor regards the two options above?

Last time I check, Google API (specifically Gmail API::list messages) use first approach.